# how to select values from teradata server view from MS sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, teradata

I need to query data in Tera database from SQLSERVER 2005. I have IP address, userid, password, db name of the tera data base. how do i query a view in teradata from sqlserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a linked Server in SQL Server 2005 to the teradata server.

Here is a blog post which describes exactly how to do it:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/phils/archive/2005/11/30/8466.aspx